# T-SQL query with aggregate function and CASE-WHEN statement

Tags: t-sql, select, group-by, aggregation, case-when

I have a simple but very important concept to clear in T-SQL.

I am writing a lot of T-SQL queries against a table, with a lot of aggregations and GROUP BY.

Now, in the `SELECT` clause of my T-SQL query, I have a CASE-WHEN statements. Please see below:

Statement 1:

```
SELECT X, Y, Z, 

A = CASE
        WHEN P = 1 THEN B
        ELSE Q
    END,

SUM(Sales)

FROM mytable

GROUP BY  
X, Y, Z,
CASE
     WHEN P = 1 THEN B
     ELSE Q
END
```

Now can Statement 1 be written as Statement 2 ?

Statement 2:

```
SELECT X, Y, Z, 

A = CASE
        WHEN P = 1 THEN B
        ELSE Q
    END,

SUM(Sales)

FROM mytable

GROUP BY  
X, Y, Z,
P, B, Q
```

Is Statement 1 = Statement 2 ?

Can the CASE-WHEN in the `SELECT` clause be modified in the `GROUP BY` clause into individual columns?

Will the result set be the same always ?

Comment: They arent' the same. Why don't you try them out? Try with this 2 examples, values for `(P, B, Q)` = `(1, 10, 100)` and `(1, 10, 200)`.

Comment: Well they are both invalid statements because of the comma after `P = 1` so they are the same in that respect.

Comment: ok, removed the commas you have mentioned; don't worry about the syntax errors please; the reason for my asking this question I get result sets for both the above queries; so don't know which one is correct

Comment: *correctness* depends on your business logic when grouping. Both selects are syntactically correct and will return results, however you will get more rows on the 2nd statement since you are grouping by 3 columns (`PBQ`) instead of 1 (the `CASE`), so the combination of different values might be more.

Answer (score 0):

The difference relies on the amount of different values you might get from columns `P`, `B` and `Q`, against the result of your `CASE` statement. You can spot the different on this example.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Data') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Data

CREATE TABLE #Data (
    P INT,
    B INT,
    Q INT,
    Sales INT)

INSERT INTO #Data (
    P,
    B,
    Q,
    Sales)
VALUES
    (1, 20, 300, 1000),
    (1, 20, 400, 500),
    (2, 1, 1, 50),
    (2, 1, 1, 250)


-- Statement 2
SELECT
    P,
    B,
    Q,
    TotalSales = SUM(D.Sales)
FROM
    #Data AS D
GROUP BY
    P,
    B,
    Q

/*
    All different combinations of PBQ and listed, and their sales added

    P   B   Q   TotalSales
    1   20  300 1000
    1   20  400 500
    2   1   1   300
*/



-- Statement 1
SELECT
    CaseResult = CASE WHEN P = 1 THEN B ELSE Q END,
    TotalSales = SUM(D.Sales)
FROM
    #Data AS D
GROUP BY
    CASE WHEN P = 1 THEN B ELSE Q END

/*

    The grouping value depends on value B when P = 1 (and not on Q!) so 
    all records with P = 1 and same B are grouped together and
    all records with P = 0 and same Q are grouped together

    CaseResult  TotalSales
    1           300
    20          1500
*/
```

There might be the case when you data doesn't generate different values from the `CASE` to the combination of `P`, `B` and `Q`, in that case the results will be the same for both queries.